# Disable or control upgrading of Firefox

Tags: firefox

> **Sorry. We just need to do one small thing to keep going.**
>
> We have just installed an update in the background. Click Restart Firefox to finish applying it.
>
> We will restore all your pages, windows and tabs afterwards, so you can be on your way quickly.

While Firefox may restore all pages, it will not restore state (E.g. YouTube video paused at 3:36). I find it OK that Firefox tells me, that there is a new version downloaded (Tor browser does that), but I want to be in control of when I want to restart.

If I had been doing a presentation in Firefox this would have been a real problem.

So how do I disable the forced restart?

My settings are:
[image: Settings]

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What OS are you using? In Debian-based Linux (like Ubuntu etc.), the solution is `sudo apt-mark hold firefox`. I beiieve that on Windows, it's a service which you could try to disable.

Comment: Have you read [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1492023)? It looks like you read that message when the executable (libraries etc) had already been updated in the background. If your OS-specific settings don't allow this in Firefox, it must be the OS. Stopping the update of Firefox and all the libraries it relies on should be enough to avoid running into this situation. It could also depend on a plug-in or an add-on, but it is unlikely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using Ubuntu (various releases) for over 10 years, and Firefox never updated automatically in background, not speaking about forced restart. I always had - and still have - to manually trigger any updates. Why?

The Ubuntu version of Firefox has Firefox's own update mechanism removed, and Firefox is updated by generic system update tool together with all other installed packages if they need an update (that's what you'd expect from a decent package management system, wouldn't you?).

In your System Settings app, go to the last tab (Information) and click Updates at the bottom of that window. In the new window that appears, click again Updates tab. You will be able to select what your system should do with security updates (as Firefox updates are classified in that category). There are three options: only notify about updates, automatically download (but not install) and automatically download & install. You probably have the last one selected - select any of the two others. Myself I prefer the first one; thus updates will never install unexpectedly, you will always have to manually trigger the update download and installation process.

(You can also turn any system updates off completely in that window, but I don't recommend that.)

Answer (score 3):

You can disable automatic updates. It seems not to be in the settings, so you need to go to about:config (you write that in the address bar). There you find "app.update.auto", and switch the value to false.

EDIT: Even with the value being false, FF still forces the restart (version 67.0.3).

Comment: doesn't work on FF 67.0.3

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-mark hold firefox
```

That command will prevent Firefox from updating. (if you installed via apt)

Answer (score 2):

As [suggested by broadcastre](https://superuser.com/a/1616905/53547), you can mark firefox to not be upgraded with

```
sudo apt-mark hold firefox
```

Then to manually upgrade it later:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold firefox
sudo apt install firefox
```

To check if firefox is currently marked as "hold" or not:

```
apt-mark showhold firefox
```

or

```
dpkg -l | grep '^h.*firefox'
```

(if the firefox line of `dpkg -l` starts with "h", it is on hold)

Answer (score 0):

I have set (in `about:config`):

```
app.update.interval = 43200000
```

I had hoped that this would postpone the update so long that I would be restarting it anyway. **But it did not.**

Had it worked it would also not be optimal: It basically disables updates, but as long as there is no way to disable the forced restarts, then it is a better solution for me.

In other words: **The problem is still not solved.**

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 : Stop updates (but not the nagging)**

- Open the menu Options
- In section General, under Firefox Updates, set
  "Check for updates but let you choose to install them".

**Method 2 : Registry update (Windows only)**

Require administrator permissions.

- Close all running Firefox instances
- Start `regedit` and navigate to the key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies`
- Create a *new key* here named `Mozilla`
- Under the Mozilla key, create a *new key* named `Firefox`
- On the right, right-click and select "New > DWORD (32-bit) Value"
  and name it `DisableAppUpdate`
- Double-click `DisableAppUpdate` and set its value to `1`
- Start Firefox.

**Method 3 : Policies file**

- Close all running Firefox instances
- Use Explorer to position to the Firefox installation folder.
  On Windows this is typically `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox`,
  but can otherwise be found in `about:support`, where it's the folder of the
  "Application Binary" entry.
- Create a sub-folder named `distribution`
- Use a text-editor (for example notepad) to create in the folder a text-file named
  `policies.json` with the following content:

  ```
    {
      "policies":
       {
         "DisableAppUpdate": true
       }
    }
  ```
- Start Firefox.

**Method 4 : prefs.js file**

- Close all running Firefox instances
- Navigate to the following location based on your operating system.

  - Windows – `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox`
  - Unix/Linux – `~/.mozilla/`
  - Mac OS X – `~/Library/Mozilla/` or `~/Library/Application Support/`
- Open the `Profiles` folder
- Open your profile folder. It is usually a bunch of characters,
  followed by ".default"
- Open the `prefs.js` file with a text editor
- Look for a line that contains `app.update.enabled`.
  Add it in if it doesn’t exist, as follows:

  ```
   user_pref("app.update.enabled", true); => Automatic updates enabled
   user_pref("app.update.enabled", false); => Automatic updates disabled
  ```

Comment: None of them actually works on Ubuntu. Have you tried? The correct way to do it on Ubuntu is via system update settings, as I have described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and most effective way, the most simple way, which ensures Firefox won't update even if Firefox somehow bypassed the registry and policy file, is to delete all files with update in its name, so Firefox would never be able to update, this method will be effective to prevent all versions of Firefox from updating...

Here is a simple cmd command that gets the job done(if you are using Windows):

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" /s /b ^| find /i "update") do del "%i" /f
```

You need elevated cmd to do this, if you don't know how, I am sure if you Google it you will find a good method that suits you.

The command lists all contents of the installation folder of firefox, which is usually "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox", and finds every file whose name contains update, and deletes all of them;

To be more precise, it will delete the following files:

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\update-settings.ini
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\updater.exe
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\updater.ini
```

If you are using Linux, this method will also work, I am sure you are able to find the path of the program and write a bash script similar to my cmd command, after all, you are using Linux...

I know this method is stupid, but it gets the jobs done, and will work on all versions across all platforms, while the smarter ways are usually platform specific...

---

If you are using Windows, in addition to deleting the update files, you should also disable Mozilla Maintenance service:

```
sc config MozillaMaintenance start=disabled
```

Comment: The question was clearly about Ubuntu and you are giving an answer related to Windows. This is not applicable at all.

Answer (score 0):

This answer likely relevant to latest Ubuntu 20.04 OP updated to recently putting bounty on question (& Firefox v80`ish).

From googling ([link 1](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/firefox-forcibly-updates-itself-after-disabling-auto-updates/61437/2), [2](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1302522), [3](https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/questions/1302913)) it appears Ubuntu includes a customized version of Firefox. It seems to stripe out some of the default settings likely to control the updating so only the most stable/tested version is probably installed & done automatically. So it appears this is 100% on Conical/whoever-makes-Ubuntu. This is either an accidental glitch or a deliberate choice by them so you'd have to engage them to fix and/or confirm. Alternatively you can [remove Ubuntu's Firefox](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-uninstall-and-update-firefox-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux): `sudo apt remove firefox`. Then install the official Mozilla one which SHOULD respect & give you options to disable the automatic updates. [These are the steps from their guide](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux):

1. Download Firefox from the [Firefox download page](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/linux/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=support.mozilla.org) to your home directory.
2. Open a Terminal and go to your home directory:
   `cd ~`
3. Extract the contents of the downloaded file:
   `tar xjf firefox-*.tar.bz2`
4. Close Firefox if it's open.
5. To start Firefox, run the firefox script in the firefox folder:
   `~/firefox/firefox`
   Firefox should now start. You can then create an icon on your desktop to run this command.
6. There's no need to keep the installation file:
   `rm firefox-*.tar.bz2`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-uninstall-and-update-firefox-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: This is completely unnecessary, as Firefox in Ubuntu is updated by generic system update mechanism, which you can completely control. I have described that in my answer.